# How do I repair a broken toilet seat anchor bolt?

Tags: toilet

The guys broke the toilet hinge anchor. It is KOHLER. I saw on their website they have a KOHLER anchor kit. Will that fit all, or is that specific for certain sizes and models?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are talking about the seat hinge?  You probably want a toilet seat hinge bolt or seat hinge, depending what exactly is broken.  A picture of the broken part will help.

Comment: I pic sure would help us understand what "hinge anchor" means to *you.*

Comment: I added a picture of the piece that is missing the anchor

Comment: Where is that piece supposed to fit? Don't recognize it...

Comment: I believe you've shown us a bolt that holds the toilet seat/hinge to the bowl. Is that correct? If that's the case, then you would have to ask the kind folks at Kohler if their bolts are generic across all their factory supplied seats (though, TBH, all the toilets I've purchased and installed have come without a seat - I've had to supply my own). (Con't...)

Comment: (...) This one looks a little different than the bolts I've had to install, so I'd suggest that it's bespoke to the seat you have. You'd probably have to contact the seat manufacturer to source a replacement. Or, just buy a whole new seat - they're not that expensive and it would probably be _much_ less hassle than trying to find a replacement for this exact part. If you can add in a pic of where this bolt came from, that might help.

Comment: I ordered a new seat and that comes with its own bolts. Like you mentioned the seat was not KOHLER so I doubt the KOHLER anchor kit would help but I will put a picture too

Comment: I just added the second photo where the broken item goes

Comment: That helps. Also, any mention of another website should be linked to that website. You're asking us to evaluate a product, so link to it using the editor.

Comment: I am just not sure if the anchor kit of KOHLER will be the solution to this or not. KOHLER said these bolts are universal . I hope so…

Comment: I did get the anchor kit. I does not look like it matches the bolt of the previous seat

Comment: I bought a new seat. Bemis 500EC 000 Toilet Seat with Easy Clean & Change Hinges, Round, Durable Enameled Wood, White